# Singluar or plural word with two modifiers

Tags: singular-vs-plural, modifiers, lists

I have an effect that is made up of two parts and I have written the following sentence to describe them:

> We test the importance of the status-enhancing and the status-suppressing components of the Matthew effect in a field experiment.

Now my colleague insists that we write the singluar "component" instead of "components". Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could, of course, be rephrased to be in the singular:

> The Matthew effect has a status-enhancing and a status-suppressing component. Here we test the importance of each in a field experiment.

This makes it clear that there is only one component of each type, which the original sentence leaves ambiguous.

But the original sentence talks about multiple components, of two types (at least one of each). The word "componentsa" must be plural in this construction.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no reason to write ‘component’ here, it would be in plural. The way the rest of the sentence is formed, you would **have to** make it plural, otherwise it would be gramatically incorrect.